# What's the equivalence of cell2mat of Matlab in Julia?

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation, julia

Well, I am not sure if some of you has encountered the same issue.
I need to convert a matlab program into julia where 'cell2mat' was extensively used.
For example a big matrix A is composed of 3*2 small matrix, see a11, a12, a21, a22, a31, a32, whose dimensions are all 4*2.
Or    `A = [a11 a12; a21 a22; a31 a32]`     with    `a11 = rand(4,2)`     for example.
I first used an `Array{Array{Float64,2},1}` type to create the whole matrix A.
Then, I need to convert this A into a usual matrix, say, `Array{Float64,2}`.
I did try to do like `hvcat((NUM),A...)`, but the order of the converted matrix doesn't correspond to the original `Array{Array{Float64,2},1}` type. 
Thanks for anyone who could provide some pistes.
Wish you all a good day!

Comment: You can use `reshape` and `C = convert(Array,VectorOfArray(B))`, where `VectorOfArray` is from [RecursiveArrayTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/RecursiveArrayTools.jl). That'll be much faster since it avoids splatting, and reshape is a view so it's free to use. The issue is just finding out how to `B = reshape(A,...)` and then `D = reshape(C,...)` to give the output you want. I have to run for now so I don't have time to finish the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with an array:

```
A = [reshape((1:8) .+ (10i+100j), 4, 2) for i in 1:3, j in 1:2]
```

so that we can visually verify that the result is correct.

Now the approach could be:

```
hcat([vcat(A[:,i]...) for i in 1:size(A,2)]...)
```

In Julia 0.7 you can use the fact that `permutedims` is not recursive to get the same in a simpler way:

```
hvcat(size(A,2), permutedims(A)...)
```

This will also work under Julia 0.6 but you have to write `permutedims(A, (2,1))`.

As a side note it is interesting (and was problematic here) that `hvcat` traverses arguments in rows, but matrices are stored in columns.

EDIT: actually `transpose` is recursive in 0.7, changed to `permutedims` which also works under 0.6.

Comment: Hello Kaminski,  it's crucial to point out that "hvcat traverses arguments in rows, but matrices are stored in columns." Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By transposing your original element of the array of array---which is matrix of course----and then transposing the final array of array in the command, such as hvcat(NUM,A...'), the correct answer can be found.